# Trying to pass contents of filenames in a folder to run an executable

Tags: powershell, for-loop, split, filenames

I have a folder with a set of files with names like `07777123456-02071234567.dat`

I need to run an executable against each file in the folder as follows:
`myexecutable.exe -orignum=07777123456 -destnum=02071234567 -file=07777123456-02071234567.dat`

My latest attempt looks like this:

```
$fileDirectory = "c:\PS";
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory)
{
    Write-Output "Processing: $file"
    $phonenumbers = $file.split("-")
    Write-Output "Originating Number: $phonenumbers[0]"
    Write-Output "Destination Number: $phonenumbers[1]" 
}
#myexecutable.exe -orignum=$phonenumber[0] -destnum=$phonenumber[1] -file=07777123456-02071234567.dat
```

I've tried a variety of combinations of `Get-ChildItem`, `File-Split` etc. I keep getting an error like:

> Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] does not contain a method named 'split'.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. Must have finally woken up.

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem *.wav -name)
{
    Write-Output "Processing: $file"
    $FileNameWithoutExtension = (Get-Item $file).Basename
    $NumbersArray = $FileNameWithoutExtension.split("-")
    $FirstNumber = $NumbersArray[0]
    $SecondNumber = $NumbersArray[1]
    Write-Output "Originating Number: $FirstNumber"
    Write-Output "Destination Number: $SecondNumber"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer works, but can be shortened to

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.wav' -File | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output "Processing: $($_.FullName)"
    $FirstNumber, $SecondNumber = $_.BaseName -split '-'
    Write-Output "Originating Number: $FirstNumber"
    Write-Output "Destination Number: $SecondNumber"

    # myexecutable.exe -orignum=$FirstNumber -destnum=$SecondNumber -file=$($_.FullName)
}
```